# Change DatePicker format/depth from Kendo Scheduler header

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a Kendo scheduler with only month view enabled. 
I would like to change the format and depth from the DatePicker on toolbar. Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i achieved this doing that way

```js
var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
scheduler._showCalendar();
$('.k-animation-container').css('display', 'none');
scheduler.popup.close();
var calendar = scheduler.calendar;
// Customize calendar here
calendar.options.start = "year";
calendar.options.depth = "year";
calendar.options.format = "MMMM yyyy";
calendar.navigateUp();
```